# Oauth2 - implement automatic logout after XX minutes of inactivity

Tags: php, api, oauth, yii2, oauth-2.0

I am using [bshaffer/oauth2-server-php](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) library for implementing oauth2 server.

Currently, I'm using access token to be authenticated on every request and refresh token when access token is expired, so if refresh token is not expired then server returns new access token. In case that refresh token is expired then following error is returned:
*{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Refresh token has expired"}* 
,and after that on client side user is automatically logged out.

I want to implement standard "PHP session timeout" with Oauth2. So my tokens will be invalid after XX minutes from last request (if there are no requests in meanwhile), meaning I'll extend validity of my tokens on each request for XX minutes.

I want expire time of refresh token to be consistent to my last request, so previous error will be returned just after XX minutes of user inactivity. Can anyone tell me what is the best practice to implement this? I thought to send refresh token in header on every request and manually extend it's expire time in database, but don't know is that secure enough.

Is this something that is handled by Oauth2, or should not be implemented on system that are using API calls?

Also, I am interested in how this case can be handled in oauth2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to tear down the architecture of Oauth 2.0 . It is designed to not care about session or cokies.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how OAuth2 works.

OAuth2 does not care about your session or users or anything else. All it does is to issue a token which is valid for a configurable amount of time. OAuth2 does application level authorization and has nothing to do with user sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a good idea to do what you want to do. But there are two ways in which you can achieve the logout functionality:

1. create a custom field in OAuth2 token session_id=xyz. Now store this session id on server store with date fields like created, used. On each request, update the used field. Once you receive a request after certain unactivity time, you go and check in DB for that session id and if time is over initiate the logout process and terminate all the session ids for that user/client and redirect the user to login page

   2. When issuing the token, issue a encrypted cookie as well which client will send along with each request. In each request you will update the cookie's read attribute and respond back. If after certain time is over and the request is received then you can decrypt the cookie and figure out if this cookie needs to be invalidated. If it is so, initiate the logout process and update the cookie with expired attribute/redirect to login page.
   3. A combination of above can be used.